# Google Sheet: Can conditional format be applied to a dynamic range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I find that conditional formatting has a huge impact on performance if it is applied to the whole column like B2:D or B2:D1000. And I don't want to make the range something like B2:D54 when I have 54 rows, because in the future I'd have to change this after new row is added to the sheet.

So the question is, in the "Apply to range" textbox, can I input some dynamic ranges?
[image]

This of course doesn't work.
Any workaround?

Comment: You cannot put formulas in the "Apply to range" box as it is only for range itself, Unfortunately, you may need to manually adjust the range in the future if you will add more rows.